# How to store symmetries of a Polyomino using pointers-to-pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, tiling

Okay so I'm working on coding a discrete tiling problem. I am storing my object called a [**polyomino**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) like so:

```
 pointer = new int*[h];
 p_0 = new int*[h];
 p_1 = new int*[h];
 p_2 = new int*[w];
 p_3 = new int*[w];
 p_4 = new int*[w];
 p_5 = new int*[h];
 p_6 = new int*[w];

 for (i=0 ; i < h ; i++)
     pointer[i] = new int[w];
     p_0[i] = new int[w];
     p_1[i] = new int[w];
     p_5[i]=new int[w];

     } 
     for(i=0 ; i < w ; i++){
     p_2[i]=new int[h];
     p_3[i]=new int[h];
     p_4[i]=new int[h];
     p_6[i]=new int[h];
     }

  for (i=0; i<h ; i++){
     for(j=0; j<w ; j++){
        cout << "What is the " << i+1;
          cout << ", " << j+1;
           cout << endl;
             cin >> k;
              if(k != 0)
                pointer[i][j]=1;      
                 else
                  pointer[i][j]=0;

      } 


}
```

Then I am generating all 8 possible orientations (the [*group of symmetries*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Symmetries_of_polyominoes) of the square) and storing them into 7 other double pointers. I was wondering if there was a way that I can make array of size 8 that holds the address for each one of my double pointers.

If I could do this, this would make my life a lot easier when checking the board to be tiled for empty spaces and then placing them. 
I would like something like:

```
         orientation[8];
         orientation[0]=pointer;
         orientation[1]=p_0;
         orientation[2]=p_1;
         orientation[3]=p_2;
         orientation[4]=p_3;
```

and so on. The problem is that there are two different sizes; one being hxw and the other being wxh. My first though was to do something like:

```
     int** orientation;
     orientation = new int*[8]

     for(i=0;i<8<;i++)
       orientation[i]=new int*[h*w];
```

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: I essentially want to make all of my orientations directly adjacent to one another in memory.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing now and what would make your life easier. Maybe post more code or rephrase the question?

Comment: I do mean pointers to pointers. I want to have a convenient way of accessing my eight 2-d matrices (where I have already generated and stored in memory. I did not include this part of the code. I will if need be). The problem i'm having is that my 4 of my matrices are hxw and 4 are wxh.

I would like something like
          Orientation[8]

Comment: orientation [0] = pointer;
orientation[1] = p_0;

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The elements of an array are stored at consecutive places in memory, so you can get the addresses and do some computations on it like this :

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int* a = &arr[0]; // Address of the beginning of the array (i.e index 0)
int* b = a + 3;   // Address of index 3, behind the scene it does a + (3 * sizeof(int))

cout << "index 0 : " << *a << endl;
cout << "index 3 : " << *b << endl << endl;

int d = 0, e = 1, f = 2;
int* arr2[] = { &d, &e, &f }; // Array of pointers
int** address = &arr2[1];     // Pointer to a pointer
int*** address_of_handle = &address; // Address of that pointer
cout << "index 1 : " << ***address_of_handle;
```

But apart from getting familiar with pointers I wonder why you wanna do this?

Comment: I would like to do this for simple "book-keeping" reasons. I feel like it may be convenient to have all of my matrices grouped together. It may be useless in the end. However, thank you for the reply! This helped a bunch

Answer (score 0):

im sorry but he is wrong you can start your array in 0 or 1 as long as you stopped your array in the exact position if you try to reach memory outside of the array you will have overflow problem alex you should read a little bit more of C/C++

Answer (score -3):

you can just declare a array of pointers double with size 8 like this

double* Arrptr[8];

and then to store the addresses you just have to use a loop which could be a for loop to store each value in an array but you will have to save one by one on the array this solution it will be better

```
double *arrptr[8];
for (int i=1;i<=8;i++)
{
    /*generate values getting them from the user or 
    you can generate them with your method*/

    cout << "Enter orientations/n";
    cin >> arrptr[i];


}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed in C and C++. This would cause an overflow and probably segfault.

Comment: Thanks for your input, even if your indices are off in the for loop. I don't think this method will work in my case, though.